# Write a function that stores information in a dictionary. Python3 Error: "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function"

Tags: python

First post. Just learning to program and post. Be kind.
While learning Python from the course "Python, A crash course" I received the error "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function"
To correct the error or at least move further in the program, I have changed the indents and completely rewrote the code.
The exact error is:

```
File "/home/billy/Desktop/python_work/solutions_exercises/Our_cars.py", line 10
    return car_dict
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

My code:

```
def make_car(manufacturer, model, **options):
    """Make a dictionary representing our cars."""
    car_dict = {
        'manufacturer': manufacture.title(),
        'model': model.title(),
        }
for option, value in options.items():
    car_dict[option] = value
    return car_dict
our_forrester = make_car('subaru', 'forrester', color='black', all_wheel_drive=True, AC=True)
print(our_forrester)    
our_tacoma = make_car('toyota', 'tacoma', color='dark green', four_wheel_drive=True, AC=True)
print(our_tacoma)
```

Comment: Use triple backticks when posting your code here. Sounds like an indentation issue but as is its impossible to see.

Comment: The most easy way to post code is to paste it in, select it and click the `{}` icon.

Comment: Remember that indentation is important in Python. That `for` loop and the rest of the statements are *not* in the `make_car` function. And the `return` statement is inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

you code indentation dose not shown correctly and i just write down it for you

```
def make_car(manufacturer, model, **options):
    """Make a dictionary representing our cars."""
    car_dict = {
        'manufacturer': manufacture.title(),
        'model': model.title(),
    }

    for option, value in options.items():
        car_dict[option] = value

    return car_dict

our_forrester = make_car('subaru', 'forrester', color='black', 
all_wheel_drive=True, AC=True)

print(our_forrester)    

our_tacoma = make_car('toyota', 'tacoma', color='dark green', 
four_wheel_drive=True, AC=True)

print(our_tacoma)
```

Comment: please flag this as answer if its correct

Answer (score 0):

Python is whitespace sensitive. Best advice I can give you is to go sit down and reread the first couple chapters of a good beginner textbook

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do

```
def make_car(manufacturer, model, **options):
  """Make a dictionary representing our cars."""
  car_dict = {
            'manufacturer': manufacture.title(),
            'model': model.title(),
            }
  # for loop is in the function
  for option, value in options.items():
    # this line is in the for loop
    car_dict[option] = value
  # this line is in the function
  return car_dict

# this is your main
our_forrester = make_car('subaru', 'forrester', color='black', all_wheel_drive=True, AC=True)
print(our_forrester)    
our_tacoma = make_car('toyota', 'tacoma', color='dark green', four_wheel_drive=True, AC=True)
print(our_tacoma)
```